# Can I optimize this function with just a loop (in first method)?

Tags: java, algorithm

I wonder if there's a way to optimize this problem with a loop (in method findPairs) that prints out the Integer pairs so that the numbers from 1 to N and the pair of numbers have a sum less than 50 and have more than 3 common divisors.

```
public class foo {
    static void findPairs(int N) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++) {
                if (commDiv(i, j) > 3 && i + j < 50)
                    System.out.println(i + " , " + j);

            }
        }

    }

    static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (a == 0)
            return b;

        return gcd(b % a, a);
    }

    static int commDiv(int a, int b) {
        int n = gcd(a, b);

        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                if (n / i == i)
                    result += 1;
                else
                    result += 2;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions about optimizing working code are generally better suited to the code review stack.

Comment: thank you. I will post on code review stack.

Comment: You could, but what would be the point of it? you'd still need to visit all pairs so folding the code into a single loop would just hurt readability and maintainability. A more reasonable optimization would be to check only pairs `(i,j)` with `i <= j` by changing the inner loop in `findPairs` to `for (int j = i; j <= N; j++) {` or storing the `gcd` results  for small arguments.